# Short key for marking checked, check box in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, troubleshooting

I am looking for a keyboard shortcut to mark a check box, that appears when filling in forms.

Comment: "I am also looking for a online tool for automated promotional ad posting for SEO purpose ?". This bit of your question is off-topic so I've removed it from your question.  See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 8):

You can use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to navigate through a form.

When you reach a checkbox [image] (the middle checkbox in the screen is the current one which is focused), press  <kbd>SPACE</kbd>  to mark it.

Comment: Also, Shift+Tab will usually navigate backwards. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can usually use `spacebar` when the checkbox is highlighted.